# $\|x+y\|^a \geq \|x\|^a + \|y\|^a$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $a \in [1, \infty), x,y \in \mathbb R^n$. Is it true that $\|x+y\|^a \geq \|x\|^a + \|y\|^a$ ?

If $a \in \mathbb N, n=1$ this is a consequence of the binomial theorem. How can I deal with the general case?

Comment: Are you sure the inequality is as posted? Because then it is obviously false. Take $y=-x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fails even when $n=1$. Consider, $$0=|1/2 - 1/2| < (1/2)^\alpha + (1/2)^\alpha$$ for all $\alpha\in [1,\infty)$. Thus we cannot have $$\|x+y\| \ge \|x\|^\alpha + \|y\|^\alpha$$ when $x=-y$.